# Why is it that the VALUES of my INSERT statement were turned to SPACES after the execution?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord, foxpro

```
//here is my function block
public function create_accnt()
{
    $post = $this->input->post(); //gets all possible posts in array form

    echo "Post array: ";print_r($post); // just to make sure that my array has    values

    $data = array(
        'userid'    => $post['user_id'],
        'lastname'  => $post['lname'],
        'firstname' => $post['fname'],
        'username'  => $post['username'],
        'password'  => $post['password'],
        'usertype'  => $post['user_type'],
        'status'    => 'A'
    ); // assigning my values to their specific fields where they will be inserted

    $query = $this->db->insert('accounts', $data); //insertion via active record

    echo "<br/>Result of db last query: "; 
    echo $this->db->last_query();//to see how my query looks in code form

    if($query)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
    // end if
} // end function

//here is the result of the code above

//Post array: Array ( [user_id] => 123456 [lname] => Smith [fname] => John [username] =>     John [password] => password [c_password] => password [user_type] => S [btn_create] => Create )

//Result of db last query: INSERT INTO accounts (userid, lastname, firstname, username, password, usertype, status) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '')
```

here why is it that after the query my VALUES were all spaces? by the way i am using CodeIgniter and my db driver is PDO and my database is DBFoxPro.

Comment: Because your post data contains space, you are saving spaces in db..first check what is coming in post and what are you saving in db..

Comment: @saveATcode Read the question carefully.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: may be i am able to get question, can you explain what he actually asking? :)

Comment: @saveATcode OP is saying why there is no data here `VALUES ('', '', '', '', '', '', '')`, its all blank.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: now can you read my comment carefully?

Comment: @saveATcode And if you read the question again carefully OP has posted this `Array ( [user_id] => 123456 [lname] => Smith [fname] => John [username] =>     John [password] => password [c_password] => password [user_type] => S [btn_create] => Create )` as post data. Don't blame on other if you haven't read the question properly.

Comment: There are blank values is a problem but I dont understand why you want to access values like this? just to minimize the code? You can access individual form value even you can clean them before insertion process like $this->input->post('user_id',true)

Comment: based on the values of my post array the result of the db last query must be something like this: INSERT INTO accounts (userid, lastname, firstname, username, password, usertype, status) VALUES ('123456', 'Smith', 'John', 'John', 'password', 'S', 'A')... right?

Comment: how does your $this->db->insert() work?...did you write the code than please provide.. or let us know if ur using some active record library.. let us know

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: alright i skipped commented lines..apology..

Comment: In relation to my style of code, I was following the documentation of Ellislab CodeIgniter in their User Guide under Active Record. that is how they showed in doing there "$this->db->insert()" function.

Comment: I was doing it before with MySql but havent had any problems, now that I am using DBF(FoxPro) via PDO DB driver, started encountering problems with this. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Have you confirmed that $data (not $post) contains the correct values? Does $this->db->_error_message() (after your insert query) return any information?

Comment: print_r($data) rather than $post. It will show either the correct data being prepared or not

Comment: I got this feedback using $this->db->_error_message() : ((null)[0] at (null):0) ... what does that mean?

Comment: @aishazafar I got this feedback: Array ( [userid] => 123456 [lastname] => Smith [firstname] => John [username] => John [password] => password [usertype] => S [status] => A ) . it means the data was prepared right. why is it after the $this->db->insert() the VALUES where all "".

Comment: Very curious. Does the query work if you run it directly in your database? INSERT INTO accounts (userid, lastname, firstname, username, password, usertype, status) VALUES ('123456', 'Smith', 'John', 'John', 'password', 'S', 'A')

Comment: @LittleBobbyLoblaw I'm using MS Access to open my Database and I think theres no section where i can type manually my queries :(

Comment: The reason I ask is because in my experience, CodeIgniter doesn't have the best handling of DB errors and sometimes does very strange things when it encouters errors it's not familiar with. Can you try the query like: $this->db->query("INSERT INTO accounts (userid, lastname, firstname, username, password, usertype, status) VALUES ('123456', 'Smith', 'John', 'John', 'password', 'S', 'A')') instead of $this->db->insert()?

Comment: @LittleBobbyLoblaw I got this result doing $this->db->query,I thought my problem was solved but when I checked my Table, nothing was added :(. Result of db last query: INSERT INTO accounts (userid, lastname, firstname, username, password, user_type, status) VALUES ('123456', 'Smith', 'John', 'John', 111, 'S', 'A')

Comment: In addition, I still got the ((null)[0] at (null):0) from the $this->db->_error_message();

Comment: Have you verified that the connection between CodeIgniter and your database is working correctly? Just add something manually (via MS Access) to your accounts table (if it's empty), then print_r($this->db->get('accounts')->result())

Comment: @LittleBobbyLoblaw Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => 201301 [lastname] => Schwan [firstname] => Carlo [username] => Carlo [password] => pass123 [user_type] => A [status] => A ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [userid] => [lastname] => [firstname] => [username] => [password] => [user_type] => [status] => ) ) ((null)[0] at (null):0)
Result of db last query: SELECT * FROM accounts : The First Record was my existing Record and the second one was the one I said earlier that was saved with empty values.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I'm stumped. For one thing, the first record has a different set of columns than the second record. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: I tried to use other active record functions like update, they returned the same empty values, whew. Anyways thank you very much for you effort and Time sir @LittleBobbyLoblaw . .

Comment: @LittleBobbyLoblaw I solved it already!. thank you very much to all of you, for you support and time. more wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `$this->db->query()` function of CI and manualy providing my query statement with it. I think `$this->db->insert()` wont work on my db DBF-foxpro via PDO driver. I also had a problem about `$this->db->where()` function. now Im just using `$this->db->query()`. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 $data = array(
        'userid'    => $post['user_id'],
        'lastname'  => $post['lname'],
        'firstname' => $post['fname'],
        'username'  => $post['username'],
        'password'  => $post['password'],
        'usertype'  => $post['user_type'],
        'status'    => 'A'
    );
```

use

```
$data = array(
        'userid'    => $this->input->post('user_id'),
        'lastname'  => $this->input->post('lname'),
        'firstname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
        'username'  => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password'  => $this->input->post('password'),
        'usertype'  => $this->input->post('user_type'),
        'status'    => 'A'
    );
```